# Sizing in Android

Tags: android, xml, layout

In my new application I want to have one Linear Layout width height: XXXdip and green background. Than show a scrollview be shown in the middle an at the Buttom of the viw there should be two Buttons like "Next" and "Back". The Scrollview contains many text.
In every tries the buttons wouldn't be shown.
I hope you could understand my bad english discription.

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="bottom|top">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout8">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/gruen" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/weiss" android:id="@+id/TextView06" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:text="@string/tx_einstellungen"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/gruen" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/weiss" android:id="@+id/first_titel" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:text="@string/app_name"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollView1">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout11" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingBottom="0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ViewFlipper android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/viewFlipperBalling" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <LinearLayout android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:paddingRight="10dip" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingTop="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/viewThanks">
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:text="@string/thanks_titel"></TextView>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="@string/app_name"></TextView>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="10dip" android:id="@+id/textView7"></TextView>
                        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/meinaquarium" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="10dip" android:id="@+id/textView8"></TextView>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/thanks_satz1" android:text="@string/thanks_satz1"></TextView>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="20dip" android:id="@+id/textView3"></TextView>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView4" android:text="@string/thanks_satz2"></TextView>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="20dip" android:id="@+id/textView5"></TextView>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView6" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="@string/thanks_satz3"></TextView>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView9" android:textSize="10dip" android:text="@string/thanks_satz4"></TextView>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="10dip" android:id="@+id/textView10"></TextView>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:paddingRight="10dip" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingTop="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/viewEinheiten">
                        <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/radioGroup1">
                            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio0" android:text="@string/tx_si_einheiten" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:checked="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"></RadioButton>
                            <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/tx_empholen_fuer_europa"></TextView>
                            <TextView android:id="@+id/textView13" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/tx_verwendete_einheiten"></TextView>
                            <TextView android:id="@+id/textView14" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="50dip"></TextView>
                            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio1" android:text="@string/tx_andere_einheiten" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"></RadioButton>
                            <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/tx_verwendet_in_us_uk"></TextView>
                            <TextView android:id="@+id/textView15" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/tx_verwendete_einheiten_us_uk"></TextView>
                        </RadioGroup>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:paddingRight="10dip" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingTop="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/viewAquarium">
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView16" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="@string/tx_name_bezeichnung"></TextView>
                        <EditText android:layout_width="250dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/et_name_erstes_aquarium"></EditText>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="25dip" android:id="@+id/textView17"></TextView>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView18" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="@string/tx_gesamt_wasservolumen"></TextView>
                        <LinearLayout android:gravity="right" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">
                            <TextView android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView25"></TextView>
                            <EditText android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="number" android:id="@+id/et_first_beckenvolumen"></EditText>
                            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView23" android:text="@string/tx_einheit_liter"></TextView>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView19" android:text="@string/tx_aquarium_einstellungen_text1"></TextView>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="25dip" android:id="@+id/textView20"></TextView>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView21" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="@string/tx_volumen_wasserwechsel"></TextView>
                        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
                            <TextView android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView26"></TextView>
                            <EditText android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="number" android:id="@+id/et_first_wasserwechsel"></EditText>
                            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView24" android:text="@string/tx_einheit_liter"></TextView>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView22" android:text="@string/tx_aquarium_einstellungen_text2"></TextView>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:paddingRight="10dip" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/viewMessmethode">
                        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout6">
                            <RadioGroup android:layout_width="220dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/radioGroup2">
                                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_messmethode_salzgehalt_salinitaet" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="@string/tx_salinitaet" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:checked="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"></RadioButton>
                                <TextView android:id="@+id/textView27" android:textSize="11dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/tx_messgerat_refr"></TextView>
                                <TextView android:id="@+id/textView28" android:textSize="11dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/tx_messaretn_satz2"></TextView>
                                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_messmethode_salzgehalt_dichte" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="@string/tx_dichte" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"></RadioButton>
                                <TextView android:id="@+id/textView29" android:textSize="11dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/tx_messart_satz4"></TextView>
                                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_messmethode_salzgehalt_relative_dichte" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="@string/tx_rel_dichte" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"></RadioButton>
                                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout10">
                                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView11" android:text="@string/bezogen_auf_"></TextView>
                                    <EditText android:text="25" android:layout_width="60dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="43dip" android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:id="@+id/input_Bezugstemperatur"></EditText>
                                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView12" android:text="@string/_c_"></TextView>
                                    <TextView android:layout_width="5dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView34"></TextView>
                                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/info_relative_dichte" android:src="@drawable/info" android:onClick="info" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                                </LinearLayout>
                                <TextView android:id="@+id/textView32" android:textSize="11dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/tx_messart_satz5"></TextView>
                                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_messmethode_salzgehalt_leitwert" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="@string/tx_leitwert" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"></RadioButton>
                                <TextView android:id="@+id/textView36" android:textSize="11dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/tx_messart_satz6"></TextView>
                            </RadioGroup>
                            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">
                                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView5" android:src="@drawable/salinitaet" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="35dip" android:id="@+id/textView30"></TextView>
                                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:src="@drawable/dichte" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="35dip" android:id="@+id/textView31"></TextView>
                                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView4" android:src="@drawable/reldichte" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="35dip" android:id="@+id/textView33"></TextView>
                                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView3" android:src="@drawable/leitwert" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/viewGraphen">
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="@string/graphen_die_nicht_angezeigt_werden_sollen_n_nwerte_die_nicht_angezeigt_werden_sollen"></TextView>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView03"></TextView>
                        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02">
                            <LinearLayout android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:gravity="center|left" android:paddingRight="10dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="10dip" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout05">
                                <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/ckAmmonium" android:text="@string/ammonium"></CheckBox>
                                <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/ckNitrit" android:text="@string/nitrit"></CheckBox>
                                <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/ckNitrat" android:text="@string/nitrat"></CheckBox>
                                <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/ckPhosphat" android:text="@string/phosphat"></CheckBox>
                                <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/ckCalcium" android:text="@string/calcium"></CheckBox>
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:gravity="center|left" android:paddingRight="10dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="10dip" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04">
                                <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/ckMagnesium" android:text="@string/magnesium"></CheckBox>
                                <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/ckAlkalinitaet" android:text="@string/alkalinit_t"></CheckBox>
                                <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/ckSilikat" android:text="@string/silikat"></CheckBox>
                                <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/ckSalinitaet" android:text="@string/salinit_t"></CheckBox>
                                <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/ckTemperatur" android:text="@string/temperatur"></CheckBox>
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </ViewFlipper>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout9">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout7">
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/img1" android:src="@drawable/dotgrey" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                    <TextView android:layout_width="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView37"></TextView>
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/img2" android:src="@drawable/dotgrey" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                    <TextView android:layout_width="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView38"></TextView>
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/img3" android:src="@drawable/dotgrey" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                    <TextView android:layout_width="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView39"></TextView>
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/img4" android:src="@drawable/dotgrey" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                    <TextView android:layout_width="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView05"></TextView>
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/img5" android:src="@drawable/dotgrey" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
                    <Button android:onClick="onWeiter" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="48dip" android:text="@string/bt_zurueck" android:id="@+id/bt_first_thanks_zurueck" android:clickable="false" android:enabled="true"></Button>
                    <Button android:onClick="onWeiter" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="48dip" android:text="@string/bt_weiter" android:id="@+id/bt_first_thanks_weiter"></Button>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

There Top Linear Layout (Green) and the Buttom Linear Layout("Next" and "Back") should always be shown, no matter what size the android phone is. And only the Scrollview should be variable.

Hope you uderstand it and could help me.

Comment: mockup can be helpful to understand your question easily

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
 <Button android:onClick="onWeiter" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="48dip" android:text="@string/bt_zurueck" android:id="@+id/bt_first_thanks_zurueck" android:clickable="false" android:enabled="true"></Button>
 <Button android:onClick="onWeiter" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="48dip" android:text="@string/bt_weiter" android:id="@+id/bt_first_thanks_weiter"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Two things :

**First** if you wanna show buttons all the time , you must put them out of the scrollView

**Second** I tell you to use RelativeLayout in order to avoid some screen sizes problems.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all, i found the Solution....

Instead of LinearLayouts now i am using RelativLayout. The Buttons at the Buttom of the Page:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

And the text wich should ONLY be scrollable in the middle of the view:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout9"
```

linearLayout9 is the LinearLayout around the Buttons
Thats all^^